# 'toLocaleDateString' is undefined in ejs template

Tags: mongodb, date, ejs

I am using ejs Html engine template with node.js.
I inserted date.now() in mongodb and now I am fetching date from mongodb in to my view and changing date format with '.toLocaleDateString()'

so, the error is showing i.e

```
'toLocaleDateString' is undefined
```

Can anyone know how to fix this issue. or any other for change the date format

Answer (score 0):

I think your value type is string. try the following code to check if it is string.

```
<% typeof you_variable %> // if should prints : string
```

If it is a string, turn the date string to date object fisrt :

```
<%  (new Date( you_variable )). toLocaleDateString() %>
```

Comment: In my Mongodb its showing 'Date' value type. and I also defined value type 'Date' in my db schema.

Comment: So what does it prints `<% typeof you_variable %>` ?

Comment: its printing `undefined`

Comment: So, of course value type `undefined` does't have method `toLocaleDateString `. You should check why `your_variable ` is undefined.

Comment: but same thing I am doing with another datepicker. then its working good.

Comment: I got the problem. Problem is that date is put in array schema in mongodb . Can you tell me how to retrieve array json data in forEach loop in ejs template. I am showing other user details with `<%=data.personaldetails.candidatename%>` so its working fine. but while I am trying to print all dates , for that i am trying `<%= data.forEach(function(xdata){%> <%= xdata.professionaldetails.company.startdate.toLocaleDateString()%>` then its not working.